# Error When Web Components Send a Message to an HTML5 Page

Tags: html, huawei-mobile-services

As I am developing huawei quick app,When Web Components send a message to an HTML5 page, the following JS error is reported:
02–14 09:22:56.329 E/jsLog (18834): [H5]Uncaught TypeError: system.onmessage is not a function
how can I solve it?

Comment: Can you provide screenshots?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ensure that the `system.onmessage` function in the HTML5 page only contains the necessary logic, that is, receiving data transmitted from a quick app page. You can leave other logic, for example, handling `onload` events, to lifecyle functions of the HTML5 page for processing.
Note that data from the quick app is not received once the `onload` event is triggered. In this case, the HTML5 page needs to listen to data receiving in polling mode. To achieve this, refer to the following sample code.

[image]

The following code is not recommended.

[image]

You should understand the mechanism for sending messages between a quick app and an HTML5 page. Then use the polling mode to solve the asynchronous data transmission problem.